# How can I change the shape of a variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: matrix, reshape, tensorflow

[TensorFlow tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/index.md#creation) says that at creation time we need to specify the shape of tensors.  That shape automatically becomes the shape of the tensor.  It also says that TensorFlow provides advanced mechanisms to reshape variables. How can I do that? Any code example?

Comment: The behavior has changed now, the shape does not automatically become the shape of the Variable anymore if `shape` is specified as an argument. See my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [shapes-and-shaping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops#Shapes_and_Shaping) from TensorFlow documentation. It describes different shape transformations available.

The most common function is probably [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#reshape), which is similar to its numpy equivalent. It allows you to specify any shape that you want as long as the number of elements stays the same. There are some examples available in the documentation.

Comment: This does not reshape the Variable but returns a Tensor that has the values of the Variable but the new shape.

Answer (score 20):

The [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) class is the recommended way to create variables, but it restricts your ability to change the shape of the variable once it has been created.

If you need to change the shape of a variable, you can do the following (e.g. for a 32-bit floating point tensor):

```
var = tf.Variable(tf.placeholder(tf.float32))
# ...
new_value = ...  # Tensor or numpy array.
change_shape_op = tf.assign(var, new_value, validate_shape=False)
# ...
sess.run(change_shape_op)  # Changes the shape of `var` to new_value's shape.
```

Note that this feature is not in the documented public API, so it is subject to change. If you do find yourself needing to use this feature, let us know, and we can investigate a way to support it moving forward.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `var.shape` is not updated accordingly. This persists when storing a checkpoint and thus prevents loading the checkpoint again, as the variable shape does not match the weight shape. Is there a way to force `var.shape` to update? Should I create a GitHub issue?

Comment: I found this thread, discussing the issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10091#issuecomment-304301817
I wonder, however, if there is a way to extend the weights of existing networks

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation shows](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md#AUTOGENERATED-shapes-and-shaping) methods for reshaping. They are:

- reshape
- squeeze (removes dimensions of size 1 from the shape of a tensor)
- expand_dims (adds dimensions of size 1)

as well as bunch of methods to get `shape`, `size`, `rank` of your tensor. Probably the most used is `reshape` and here is a code example with a couple of edge cases (-1):

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
])
v2 = tf.reshape(v1, [2, 6])
v3 = tf.reshape(v1, [2, 2, -1])
v4 = tf.reshape(v1, [-1])
# v5 = tf.reshape(v1, [2, 4, -1]) will fail, because you can not find such an integer for -1
v6 = tf.reshape(v1, [1, 4, 1, 3, 1])
v6_shape = tf.shape(v6)
v6_squeezed = tf.squeeze(v6)
v6_squeezed_shape = tf.shape(v6_squeezed)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = sess.run([v2, v3, v4, v6, v6_shape, v6_squeezed, v6_squeezed_shape])
# print all variables to see what is there
print e # shape of v6
print g # shape of v6_squeezed
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.Variable(tf.placeholder(tf.float32))
```

is not valid at tensorflow 1.2.1

in python shell:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Variable(tf.placeholder(tf.float32))
```

You will get:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Placeholder:0", dtype=float32)
```

Update: if you add `validate_shape=False`, there will be no error.

```
tf.Variable(tf.placeholder(tf.float32), validate_shape=False)
```

if `tf.py_func` matches your requirement:

```
def init():
    return numpy.random.rand(2,3)
a = tf.pyfun(init, [], tf.float32)
```

You can create variable that has any shape by passing your own init function.

Another way:

```
var = tf.get_varible('my-name', initializer=init, shape=(1,1))
```

You can pass `tf.constant` or any `init` function that returns numpy array. The shape provided will not be validated. The output shape is your real data shape.

Answer (score 1):

**`tf.Variable`: Use the `shape` argument with `None`**

A [feature was added](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f9f2547b085969c67dc140aaa230551b6471a956) in 1.14 that allows to specify unknown shapes.

If `shape` is `None`, the initial shape value is used.

If `shape` is specified, this is used as the shape and allows to have `None`.

Example:

```
var = tf.Variable(array, shape=(None, 10))
```

This allows to later on assign values with shapes matching the shape above (e.g. arbitrary shapes in axis 0)

`var.assign(new_value)`

Answer (score 1):

As said by Mayou36, you can now change the variable shape after it was first declared. Here is a working example:

```
v = tf.Variable([1], shape=tf.TensorShape(None), dtype=tf.int32) 
tf.print(v)
v.assign([1, 1, 1])
tf.print(v)
```

And this outputs:

```
[1]
[1 1 1]
```