# Initializing a shared variable with unknown shape

Tags: tensorflow

The `Variable` initializer provides a `validate_shape` parameter so that you can change a `Variable` shape after initialization.

However, it doesn't look like `get_variable()` has that parameter and instead uses the default value of `validate_shape=False` when creating a new `Variable`. How can you create a shared `Variable` whose shape you can change after initialization?

Comment: Currently this isn't supported in the Variable Scope API (for shared variables). Can you share more about your use case, in case there is an alternative workaround that we can suggest?

Comment: @mrry I was implementing the methods from the Net2Net paper arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05641v2.pdf (which the authors say they did in tensorflow) and had to be able to change the shape of some of the weight and bias tensors after training a model for some time. Ultimately I used tf.assign using the method you mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33662680/1187026 . It seemed to work but I haven't tested my implementation thoroughly enough to be sure and am only using it in a single GPU environment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems based on the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable)
that the `validate_shape` parameter is now supported as desired, in case anyone else stumbles upon this question.