# Adding information into a tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, arrays, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Currently I have a neural network that convolutes and pools images. However, right before I make my densely connected layer, I want to add some information. Currently, I reshape my image to a flat tensor with `tf.reshape(image, [width * length * channels])`, but I was wondering how I could append a couple of `tf.float32` values to the end of the tensor?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913762/how-to-expand-a-tensorflow-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape to a vector using [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) with `-1`:

```
tf.reshape(image, [-1])
```

and append the new values as Tensors using [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat):

```
tf.concat([image, new_val1, new_val2], 0)
```

This will return a Tensor resulting from concatenation of the input tensors.