# Tensorflow: How to convert a rank 1 tensor into a rank 2 tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, rank

I'm trying to make a simple neural network and I have a simple question: How do I convert a tensor which is rank 1 to a tensor which is rank 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the shape of a variable in TensorFlow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654754/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-variable-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for `tf.expand_dims()` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims