# How to delete existed tensorflow variable?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using windows GPU tensorflow 1.0. I want to delete useless or wrong tf variable.

```
For example I run code and generate a bad model, then I copy code and just modify existed variable W1(shape=[3,3],name="W1") as W1(shape=[5,5],name="W1") and run.  

 However tensorflow generate W1(shape=[5,5],name="W1_1") rather than replace old W1. So in the end Tensorflow will save both wrong trained W1(name='w1') and trained w1(name='w1_1'). When I restore W1, tensorflow give me wrong trained W1(name='w1').
```

Could you tell me how to delete old variable W1 and add new W1?

(the newline edit function is useless)

Comment: reformulate in a cleaner way. I don’t understand what you mean. provide some code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve by changing the shape of your variable. If you would have asked the question in such a way we knew your intent, maybe we could help you better.

Now there are multiple options to solve your problem: 
- ignore the name of your variable (what bugs does it cause??)
- remove all variables: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#reset_default_graph
- Change the shape of the variable instead of defining a new one. Check the answer of mrry here: [How can I change the shape of a variable in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654754/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-variable-in-tensorflow)

Comment: I rewrite my question. In a word, I want to handle every variable precisely. It seems there is no way to modify the existed variables. Maybe I have to clear all variable and restart. Your answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck!