# How to change shape of variable in Tensorflow Java?

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a matrix (a Tensorflow variable) whose shape is determined dynamically. So I need to re-assign matrix while creating the graph. In python, we have [options of resetting the graph or reassigning the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654754/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-variable-in-tensorflow) by setting `validate_shape` to False.

Code Snippet:

Embedding matrix in tensorflow graph:

```
embedding_matrix = tf.get_variable("EMB_MATRIX",
                                        shape=[vocab_size, 300],
                                        dtype=tf.float32,
                                        initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, dtype=tf.float32),
                                        trainable=False)
```

Re-assigning the embedding matrix with new shape:

```
word_emb_matrix = np.insert(word_emb_matrix, vocab_size, np.arange(300), axis=0) # Inserting one row into embedding matrix
session.run(tf.assign(mtrain.embedding_matrix, word_emb_matrix, name="EMB_MATRIX", validate_shape=False)) #Assign embedding matrix with new shape
```

Now, when we use saved model/graph in Java, how can same functionality be achieved?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question here? For example, when you say you have a "matrix", are you talking about a [Java `Tensor` object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Tensor) or a node in the graph, i.e., a [Java  `Output` object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Output), or something else?

Comment: It's a node in the graph. So basically, I am trying to use a python-saved graph in Java. But, there's one node in the graph (a Tensorflow variable as a matrix) which needs to be re-assigned based on current dataset. Rest all graph remains same. Does this clear the question?

Comment: I'm not quite following. Is it possible for you to edit the question to include code snippets (e.g., Python code that does what you want and/or the Java code you have up to the point that you're stuck)

Comment: Okay! I have updated the question with the code snippet about what is required to be achieved.